# critical problem with download links in my project with php

Tags: php

helooo alll ...my project is to upload file and download it.all going right in local server but when try run project in my server in internet and click in link to download word file (doc / docx) it open error page

```
The page cannot be found

The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

however it view pdf file without any problem how i can solve that problem and how make site download pdf without view it in browser

Answer (score 2):

The only part I could answer that wasn't vague is...

> how make site download pdf without view it in browser

You can send headers to make the browser download the file.

You can have a file like `download-pdf.php`...

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($file)) {
  die('No file');
}

if ( ! is_file($file)) {
  die('File does not exist');
}

if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'pdf') {
  die('PDF files only');
}

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=your-filename.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($file);
```

Of course, `die()` sucks, so use something more appropriate.